# Returning Resolve Value of Promises

Tags: javascript, synchronous

I'm working with promises to hit an API for the sunset and sunrise time for a certain area. I can console log the resulting `sunset` but returning it does not return the same value.
Ex.
console.log(sunset) => 17:52
return sunset = undefined
Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Show us your code, otherwise we cannot help you out.

Comment: No, you cannot get the *future* fulfillment value of the promise. You can only return the promise itself, and let the caller wait for it using a `then` callback.

Comment: What's probably happening is sometimes the promise is fulfilled by the time you print it out, sometimes it's not. Read all this:   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise